# Killing rsync softly

Tags: rsync, kill

Is there a way of tell `rsync` to stop whenever possible in a clean way? Two options:

- tell `rsync` to stop transfering the current file, clean any temp file and exit;
- or let `rsync` end the transfer of the current file and then stop.

By doing <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> it does stop *mid-transfer* and leaves the temporary files there, right?

### Edit

Even if using `--inplace`? What would be the best course of action? I'm using `rsync` with `--inplace` and I have to go fast, how can I say “May be end with this file then quit, or quit now, but clean this file you were copying so you don't leave corrupt things (I don't care if it's removed, I can backup again later)” or something like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you kill rsync with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> it does stop it mid transfer but it will not keep any temporary files there unless running with the `--partial` option.

For those also interested in just pausing rsync, if you press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> it pauses the program.  When you resume it by running `fg` or `bg` rsync will reiterate over the file that it didn't finish and continue downloading the rest of the files.
To see all currently paused programs run `jobs`

**About --inplace**

The problem with --inplace is that it does not create a new file when updating data, it just writes to the existing one. If you press ctrl + c while running with --inplace and it is updating an existing file it will leave a half finished file without removing it. Also if you are syncing only new files and not updating existing ones then when you cut off a transfer (with ctrl + c) it will leave a half finished file that it won't remove. Just a note I would not recommend --inplace for OS files. You can really jack up some things (because they change frequently)

Comment: Okey, so `ctrl + C` is *precisely* “letting `rsync` close”, right? I mean, it doesn't stop abruptly, it just sends a message to `rsync` “Please, stop now” and `rsync` will stop the transfer, clean whatever he was doing and then quit by itself. In that case, that's perfect. With `ctrl + Z` the problem is that I want to shut down the computer because I've to go.

Comment: @Manuel Yes correct.  I can edit my answer around if you will mark it as correct?

Comment: Good to know that `ctrl + C` is a clean way to stop it.

Comment: What about `--inplace`, what would be the best course of action? I'm using `rsync` with `--inplace` and I have to go fast, how can I say “May be end with this file then quit, or quit now, but clean this file you were copying so you don't leave corrupt things (I don't care if it's removed, I can backup again later)”.

Comment: @Manuel The problem with `--inplace` is that it does not create a new file when updating data, it just writes to the existing one.  If you press `ctrl + c` while running with `--inplace` and it is updating an existing file it will leave a half finished file *without* removing it.  Also if you are syncing only new files and not updating existing ones then when you cut off a transfer (with `ctrl + c`) it will leave a half finished file that it won't remove. I tested all this btw.

Comment: That wouldn't possibly corrupt anything, right? The next time I run `rsync` it just starts from that file an keep updating it and complete with the rest of the files. If that's it, then no problem.

Comment: @Manuel If you are doing a one way sync (Folder A > Folder B) and not bidirectional (Folder A <> Folder B) then no, you shouldn't have any problems as long as you continue the sync ASAP because the unfinished files won't be cleaned up.  Just a note I would not recommend `--inplace` for OS files.  You can really jack up some things (because they change frequently)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, that's a good point. I hope there was an option to stop `rsync` just after the current file it's transferring.